# List all videos of a YouTube channel in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube Data API to list first 25 video titles and ids of a channel in google spreadsheet, but for some reason I'm only getting the Title of the channel.

Here are my codes:

```
function searchByChannel() {
    var results = YouTube.Channels.list('id,snippet', {
        id: 'UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ',
        maxResults: 25
    });

    var title = "";
    var id = "";
    var lr = 0;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
        var item = results.items[i];
        title = item.snippet.title;
        id = item.id.videoId;
        lr = sheet1.getLastRow() + 1;
        sheet1.getRange(lr, 1).setValue(title);
        sheet1.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(id);
        lr++;
    }
}
```

I'm new to YouTube data api so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. How can I list 25 video ids and titles in my spreadsheet using google apps script?

Comment: If I run this script, it got error with the message that it can't find Youtube object in the first line. How can I import the object? Is there something I have to declare in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the `YouTube.Channels` states that it will return information about the Channel, nothing about the videos, that's why your getting the channel's info.

`YouTube.Search` on the other hand gather info about videos, and you can feed it a `channelId` parameter that will seek into a specified channel, as such, your result code should look like:

```
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    channelId:'UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ',
    maxResults: 25
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the titles but not the video ids. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: N. B. - I'm getting the playlist's titles and if I use `item.id` then I can get the playlist's ids. But I was looking for video titles and ids. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the method to get all videos using channel url http://www.gappsscript.com/get-a-list-of-videos-in-a-channel-using-youtube-service/

Comment: This solution provided the video IDs for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965119/how-to-get-information-about-all-videos-of-a-channel-to-google-sheets-with-googl/66965120#66965120