# How to manipulate Youtube Brand Channel through Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube

I'm trying to manipulate items inside my Youtube Brand Channel, using the YouTube Service provided by Google Apps Script, but it only works for my "personal" channel and not the Brand Channel of whom I'm owner.

I'm wondering if anyone has been able to make it work, something as simple as create or update a playlist inside such channel keep throwing a "Forbidden" message when on a playlist inside my "personal" channel is alright.

I even have my brand channel as my default channel, as Google suggest doing this for services that don't support switching between channels and it has no effect whatsoever.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/F2-SIFu0j04/y00XwI3UBEoJ), even if the channel is for a brand, it's just a normal user channel. So, [YouTube Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube) should also work in your Brand Channel. Be noted that this is an advanced service that must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) and Apps Script requires user authorization to access private data from built-in Google services or advanced Google services.

If you're receiving [forbidden (403)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) error, make sure that your request is properly authorized.

References:

- [List all videos of a Youtube channel in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111170/list-all-videos-of-a-youtube-channel-in-google-apps-script)
- [Subscribe to channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/apps-script#subscribe_to_channel)
- [Getting the details of uploads to any YouTube channel into a Google Sheet](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/07/getting-the-details-of-uploads-to-any-youtube-channel-into-a-google-sheet/)