# Google Apps Script: Retrieve most recent video ids from Youtube API v3 as array

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

I am working on a project where I have an external application call a Google Apps Script Function whose purpose is to retrieve the id's of the most recent uploads on a youtube channel. [The script provided by google works very well at getting the video id's:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube)

```
/**
 * This function retrieves the user's uploaded videos by:
 * 1. Fetching the user's channel's.
 * 2. Fetching the user's "uploads" playlist.
 * 3. Iterating through this playlist and logs the video IDs and titles.
 * 4. If there is a next page of resuts, fetching it and returns to step 3.
 */
function retrieveMyUploads() {
  try {
    // @see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
    const results = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {
      mine: true
    });
    if (!results || results.items.length === 0) {
      console.log('No Channels found.');
      return;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
      const item = results.items[i];
      /** Get the channel ID - it's nested in contentDetails, as described in the
       * Channel resource: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels.
       */
      const playlistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
      let nextPageToken = null;
      do {
        // @see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
        const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {
          playlistId: playlistId,
          maxResults: 25,
          pageToken: nextPageToken
        });
        if (!playlistResponse || playlistResponse.items.length === 0) {
          console.log('No Playlist found.');
          break;
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {
          const playlistItem = playlistResponse.items[j];
          console.log('[%s] Title: %s',
              playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
              playlistItem.snippet.title);
        }
        nextPageToken = playlistResponse.nextPageToken;
      } while (nextPageToken);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with err %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to actually use the output of this function for my application. From what I can see, the function simply prints the id's to the execution log, but I am wondering if there is a way to put the output into an array? I have seen this [SO post that accomplishing the same task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965119/how-to-get-information-about-all-videos-of-a-channel-to-google-sheets-with-googl). However, I am wondering if it can be done using the script that google provides in their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question...you want an array of uploaded videos from a given channel. If so, you need to create an array where to store the results.

Here is a tested function that gets the uploaded videos from a given channel:

```
function getUploadedVideos() {
  try {
    // Call uploaded videos from channel "Listen To This": 

    /** Array with the data. */
    var array_videos = [];

    /** Token pagination. */
    var nextPageToken = "";

    /** Channel "Listen To This". */
    var channel_id = "UC6ZVjGqRf7elKAcYTXCaIsw";

    /** "upload" playlist = it's the channel_id, but change the first letters "UC" to "UU" */
    var uploads_playlist_id = ("UU" + channel_id.substr(2, channel_id.length));

    /**
     * Get all uploaded videos by the channel.
     */
    do {
      const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {
        playlistId: uploads_playlist_id, // also works with "mine: true" for get YOUR uploaded videos.
        maxResults: 50,
        // Here, the first time the call is made, the "nextPageToken" value 
        // is empty. In every iteration (if "nextPageToken" is retrieved), 
        // the "nextPageToken" is used - in order to get the next page.
        pageToken: nextPageToken
      });
      if (!playlistResponse || playlistResponse == undefined) {
        Logger.log('No playlist found.');
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No playlist found.");
        break;
      }

      // Write the videos returned in the response: 
      for (let j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {
        const mySubItem = playlistResponse.items[j];
        array_videos.push(mySubItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
      }

      // Check the token: 
      try {
        if (playlistResponse.nextPageToken != null || playlistResponse.nextPageToken != undefined) {
          nextPageToken = playlistResponse.nextPageToken;
        } else {
          nextPageToken = undefined;
          break;
        }
      } catch (ex_page) {
        // An error occurred. Check closely the code.
        Logger.log("An error occurred. Check closely the code.");
      }
    } while (nextPageToken != undefined);

    // Print the results: 
    Logger.log(array_videos);
  } catch (ex) {
    Logger.log("Error at getting Marvel videos: %" + ex);
  }
}
```

Result:

```
[lkD6zqBd15k, SalMSotJojg, 6rzKW6v_K9Q, goWF8wbNWcs, q0ElGPy6l9I, xPLOnypPgOI, rJHdvyntjZk, LzuA87yMHM8, bdgJAPXySVg, CMJbgwqmmAA, qmM_nsHTdGg, NZg5M0Vek6k, LHkZKohT5Mg, W7Oxs1O58po, lz-Q7zOE1TE, o5uZL3yUnQ8, VwMQC9Ki6-A, KfKujQcSr6I, IkPb88qUgk0, cilE6-mDiZc, sWKXnoTbgEc, MMN4HbX_UdA, EZG0nbXgJyQ, 9dCCrM8Amdo, FZquT-IN1BI, nq0F3mS4wxw, Mb70SJgZVlM, hkEV1obRwXw, ewNlaQQ4zik, ptaNPp6waws, DsGV5FnH4to, DfQWxfNUT3k, a7_O0LqeACI, Z--uRxZAMs8, PkD3a0FPEGI, MzGKo5tF_Y0, vd2fsou_Phg, HFtL2FxOk4I, q5Hy7nZmqu8, 4dKss-2FFEA, pj-4olXN0Eg, i0dYCCAuRbE, inyuMUxXiCs, LHnUZGQ4Q1g, llMrn70YKKI, -IaCwFk8ahI, DvoV4PuoJ5I, SUKmRCFx0DQ, nVbgXA_vdzo, xjTMp7YL0tc, ePIoXemhFcM, twKr8t_d_Wo, 69YMCEE7lJs, Ie61ZeWMNig, UrT7URgGr2Y, I3TdwIRHGs8, 407nKV2wXVk, RVQgmjFyxNc, H5lmadddLuE, rqCNRuO-b2g, P5LFeAUbuQQ, H3pIHb99Pwg, aixhKlvboao, WllI0h4np2s, lM6jSit1HOc, XzdmhbZPtoI, a2ky2jqPKik, WoO694aGQS0, QvNgRVDrwKk, TgndfBuHv80, a07dwCbInqw, BJijluHVN0o, peMxsRTMdAU, i4pTDiVglyQ, zCFbq7xq7WM, e2njchHP_IE, lTvvUgIt4CM, bJQG7_oydKQ, xHJHYFPn-3I, vXAPxN-b6rI, DmVPJztgqpM, BbxnEkavYcc, ZKJb3RBR5-g, traXftfW8n4, HC0-_v7oql4, ywBipoo7zKU, 0j1To_VTc2U, osmrXqRuwJA, p65aE3XWSp8, rrrtmhAtxVw, 9L13dJ2GY8Y, VCgKCtwEWZQ, 8EJJH6qrsA8, QoOOsIJbXKQ, MngpR1BS--Y, iAFIkRchafs, AtOJZDDSrsQ, h0qms723EQw, Kcqqk7FVPmA, E3K4RwL7SY4, nQAENgf-qhk, HqVr0Yrozrs, tmQqUh0xark, deBhz0mADOw, 29ntukJ8C9Q, Jj_3x8fnU0M, Q90061dShXU, ed1oIgcjlNc, WPzCfboz7BA, j9FNonwudEk, p5FTI8q4bBg, 5Mk5EMiCy3k, rD0UamFoq7M, 47EP94Kz-yw, XyitdaXLzDk, y-Faj25nOhM, SZ1jUnfybuQ, EALd5UOXEVc, Tzc1SMxCtos, bHf5mJ86fwA, 25lGn8XVWj4, lCZc9y9KpY4, HCP3NOKrdOc, N12WWl_f3QM, 1a5fIFoCyl0, AA3WjWD_hyM, JE1DystO6DA, oaNdiTLKlMA, dQsWBeMuOeU, q1egg1mlxvM, 8xzUYxx541E, UJg99jDuU7c, TaUOspOh5pU, 0EtJgT9bS3o, MzbYsoR9dPM, 9sE138cu_LU, Ej1nxBxFSKc]
```

Comment: Yep you nailed it. Thank you for putting this together. I am still fairly new to GAS but not to coding, so I can understand what the original code was doing, but my inexperience in GAS and the Youtube api was making it really hard to figure out how to adjust the script to get the output I needed. I see what you were doing by creating the array first and pushing the id within the loop off of the playlistResponse. This will help me in the future with GAS so thank you for writing this and making it clear to what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This was able to grab the id of the most recent video uploaded on a channel and is a cleaned up version of above [grabbed from here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/apps-script/youtube.gs):

```
function retrieveMyUploads3() {
  var results = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {mine: true});

  for(var i in results.items) {
    var item = results.items[i];
    // Get the playlist ID, which is nested in contentDetails, as described in the
    // Channel resource: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels
    var playlistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
    var playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list(`snippet`, {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        maxResults: 1,
      });
    var chunk = playlistResponse.items.shift()
    var theID = chunk.snippet.resourceId.videoId.toString()
    return theID


    
  }
}
```

Not quite an array of many different one's but I am sure it can be looped to build the array of id's and serves as a condensed way to get ahold of the video id's compared to the original google version if you don't need id's beyond the first page of results